# "React does not recognize the `classsName` prop on a DOM element"

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React application and keep running into an error that I don't understand. I can't find it anywhere else. My understanding is that within a JSX element I should always use "className" instead of the "class" attribute. But, I get this warning:

```
index.js:2178 Warning: React does not recognize the `classsName` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `classsname` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
```

Anyone seen this before or have an idea what I got wrong?

Comment: ```classsName``` should be ```className```